# The "Do While False" idiom

Tags: code-golf

## Do While False

At work today one of my colleagues was describing the use-case for do while(false). The person he was talking to thought that
this was silly and that simple if statements would be much better. We then proceeded to waste half of our day discussing the best
manner to write something equivalent to:

```
do
{
   //some code that should always execute...

   if ( condition )
   {
      //do some stuff
      break;
   }

   //some code that should execute if condition is not true

   if ( condition2 )
   {
       //do some more stuff
       break;
   }

   //further code that should not execute if condition or condition2 are true

}
while(false);
```

This is an idiom which is found in c quite often.
Your program should produce the same output as the below pseudo-code depending on the conditions.

```
do
{
   result += "A";

   if ( C1)
   {
      result += "B";
      break;
   }

   result += "C"

   if ( C2 )
   {
       result += "D";
       break;
   }

   result += "E";

}
while(false);

print(result);
```

Therefore the input could be:

```
1. C1 = true, C2 = true
2. C1 = true, C2 = false
3. C1 = false, C2 = true
4. C1 = false, C2 = false
```

and the output should be:

```
1. "AB"
2. "AB"
3. "ACD"
4. "ACE"
```

This is code-golf so answers will be judged on bytes.
Standard loopholes are banned.

Yes this is a simple one, but hopefully we will see some creative answers, I'm hoping the simplicity will encourage people to use languages they are less confident with.

Comment: Does the output have to be uppercase, or is lowercase also permitted?

Comment: Are the ```"``` marks required? Also, is a trailing space ok?

Comment: As an aside for the debate with your coworker, it seems to me you could accomplish the same thing using a method with `return result` in place of `break`. Then you get the bonuses of re-usability and simplifying the calling code, too. But perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I didn't know this was an idiom in C...

Comment: @Mehrdad some folks do this instead of `goto` because using `goto` is bad form :)

Comment: @Seth: Yeah I understood why when I saw it, I'd just never seen it. :P

Comment: The only time I have ever used `do{}while(false)` is inside macros. A simple `if` does not suffice, because it interacts badly with `else`s around that may be present. Without a macro you may as well remove the `do` and `while`.

Comment: @Seth This is a poor man's `goto` and if you think `goto` is bad form you sure as heck shouldn't be using this. @nwp hit the nail on the head for the major usecase of this idiom. +1

Comment: @Poke - `break` is more like the *rich* man's `goto` (it's safer than plain `goto` because it's constrained to *jumping forwards* and *exiting scopes* - no entering new scopes without initializing their variables, for example).

Answer (score 18):

## Python 3, 31

Saved 1 byte thanks to xnor.

Only one byte away from ES6. :/ Stupid Python and its long anonymous function syntax.

Hooray for one liners!

```
lambda x,y:x*"AB"or"AC"+"ED"[y]
```

Test cases:

```
assert f(1, 1) == "AB"
assert f(1, 0) == "AB"
assert f(0, 1) == "ACD"
assert f(0, 0) == "ACE"
```

Comment: If you re-order `x*"AB"`, you can save the space after.

Comment: Sorry, your long, anonymous function syntax will be the death of python :P

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I knew something had to be holding Python back. I'll submit a PEP ASAP.

Comment: You do that, and [I'll order snake traps](https://xkcd.com/1523/)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ heh.

Comment: I just want JavaSnakes.

Comment: A PEP to make `λ` a synonym of `lambda` would be great :)

Comment: @RobertGrant It's a shame it's 2 bytes, but yeah, `λx,y:` would be fantastic.

Comment: @MorganThrapp pretty sure Haskell can do `λx y->` already. Behind a language extension, unfortunately, but `\x y->` is just as fine.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ and Morgan'Venti'Thrappuccino: See [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/PythoLambda).

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Fascinating! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>30</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

A simple anonymous function taking two inputs. Assign to a variable to call.
**Update**: Let's jump on the index bandwagon. It saves 4 bytes. *I have secured my lead over Python*. Saved a byte by currying the function; call like `(...)(a)(b)`. Thanks Patrick Roberts!

```
a=>b=>a?"AB":"AC"+"ED"[b]
```

Old, original version, 30 bytes (included to not melt into the python answer `(;`):

```
(a,b)=>"A"+(a?"B":b?"CD":"CE")
```

Comment: This isn't that clever...

Comment: @theonlygusti This a code-golf, not a popularity contest. Also, why waste bytes being clever if there is a more concise solution?

Comment: I like your choice of nose `:b?`

Comment: @JAtkin Indeed!

Comment: I think varibles x and y need to be replaced with a and b

Comment: @ShaunH Ah, thanks. My mistake.

Comment: Grrrrrrr, stupid javascript.

Comment: You can save a byte with [currying](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8427/42091)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ahhh haven't committed that one to memory yet

Answer (score 13):

## C preprocessor macro, 34

- 1 byte saved thanks to @TobySpeight

```c
#define f(a,b)a?"AB":b?"ACD":"ACE"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ZY9NbsMgEIX3PsWIqJJJaIqzjJNU/ckpUi/IGBKkFleAu2jksztj2XUdhQXwzXvMPPDxhNi2s1Ib6zSYVIkjV8/s5ZWtj3S8vbM17XvWzqzDz7rUsAmxtNXyvEsgsS7Cl7IO0u6m/AkF4Fl5mM8JfjhcEqDViTYnfwch@hrjoPQaZvmUVj01EHWIqIIOhwK244tLJiBrxITkP8kbTXZa3@xvvKk8paV2MgcLGwj2V1cmHUdxeLqrHWTByb1Y8DHEt6eoJmUP4cMxAVOzLZZIoW4LK86HXw05vI61d5Qiador).

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 15 <s>17</s> bytes

```
?'AB'}'AC'69i-h
```

Inputs are `0` or `1` on separate lines. Alternatively, `0` can be replaced by `F` (MATL's `false`) and `1` by `T` (MATL's `true`).

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=PydBQid9J0FDJzY5aS1o&input=MAowCg)

```
?           % if C1 (implicit input)
  'AB'      %   push 'AB'
}           % else
  'AC'      %   push 'AC'
  69        %   push 69 ('E')
  i-        %   subtract input. If 1 gives 'D', if 0 leaves 'E'
  h         %   concatenate horizontally
            % end if (implicit)
```

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 28 bytes

```
x#y|x="AB"|y="ACD"|1<2="ACE"
```

Usage example: `False # True` -> `"ACD"`.

Using the input values directly as guards.

Answer (score 9):

### Brainfuck, 65 bytes

This assumes that C1 and C2 are input as raw 0 or 1 bytes.  e.g.

```
echo -en '\x00\x01' | bf foo.bf
```

Golfed:

```
++++++++[>++++++++<-]>+.+>+>,[<-<.>>-]<[<+.+>>,[<-<.>>-]<[<+.>-]]
```

Ungolfed:

```
                                      Tape
                                      _0
++++++++[>++++++++<-]>+.+  print A    0 _B
>+>,                       read C1    0 B 1 _0  or  0 B 1 _1
[<-<.>>-]<                 print B    0 B _0 0  or  0 B _1 0
[<+.+>>                    print C    0 D 1 _0
    ,                      read C2    0 D 1 _0  or  0 D 1 _1
    [<-<.>>-]<             print D    0 D _0 0  or  0 D _1 0
    [<+.>-]                print E    0 D _0    or  0 E _0
]
```

I believe it worth noting that this solution *is* in fact based on breaking out of while loops.

Answer (score 7):

## GNU Sed, 21

```
/^1/cAB
/1$/cACD
cACE
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/2GUPrv).

Answer (score 7):

## [NTFJ](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/NTFJ/), 110 bytes

```
##~~~~~#@|########@|~#~~~~~#@*(~#~~~~#~@*########@^)~#~~~~##@*##~~~~~#@|########@|(~#~~~#~~@*):~||(~#~~~#~#@*)
```

More readable:

```
##~~~~~#@|########@|~#~~~~~#@*(~#~~~~#~@*########@^)~#~~~~##@*##~~~~~#@|########@|(~#~~~#~~@*
):~||(~#~~~#~#@*)
```

That was certainly entertaining. [Try it out here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/NTFJ/), using two characters (`0` or `1`) as input.

Using ETHProduction's method for converting to 0, 1 (characters) to bits, this becomes simpler.

```
##~~~~~#@|########@|
```

This is the said method. Pushing 193 (`##~~~~~#@`), NANDing it (`|`) with the top input value (in this case, the first char code, a 48 or 49). This yields 254 for 1 and 255 for 0. NANDing it with 255 (`########@`) yields a 0 or 1 bit according to the input.

```
~#~~~~~#@*
```

This prints an `A`, since all input begins with `A`. `*` pops the `A` when printing, so the stack is unchanged from its previous state.

```
(~#~~~~#~@*########@^)
```

Case 1: the first bit is `1`, and `(` activates the code inside. `~#~~~~#~@*` prints `B`, and `########@^` pushes 255 and jumps to that position in the code. This being the end of the program, it terminates.

Case 2: the first bit is `0`. `(` skips to `)` and the code continues.

```
~#~~~~##@*
```

This prints a `C`, because that's the next character.

```
##~~~~~#@|########@|
```

This converts our second input to a bit.

```
(~#~~~#~~@*)
```

If our second bit is a 1, we proceed to print an `E`.

```
:~||
```

This is the NAND representation of the Boolean negation of our bit: `A NAND (0 NAND A) = NOT A`.

```
(~#~~~#~#@*)
```

This now activates if the bit was a `0`, and prints `E`.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
+\A?Q\B+\C?E\D\E
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%5CA%3FQ%5CB%2B%5CC%3FE%5CD%5CE&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A1%0A1%0A0%0A0%0A1%0A0%0A0&debug=0&input_size=2)

Ternaries!

Explanation:

```
+\A              Start with an A
?Q\B             If the first variable is true, add a B and break.
+\C              Otherwise, add a C and
?E\D             If the second variable is true, add a D and break.
\E               Otherwise, add a E and finish.
```

Input on two consecutive lines.

Comment: Oh pythmaster, make known to us the ways of this program. ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Pyth, 13 chars, 19 bytes

```
.HC@"૎્««"iQ2
```

Takes input in form [a,b]

Explanation

```
               - autoassign Q = eval(input())
           iQ2 -    from_base(Q, 2) - convert to an int
   @"૎્««"    -   "૎્««"[^]
  C            -  ord(^)
.H             - hex(^)
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.HC%40%22%E0%AB%8E%E0%AB%8D%C2%AB%C2%AB%22iQ2&input=%5B0%2C1%5D&debug=0)

[Or use a test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.HC%40%22%E0%AB%8E%E0%AB%8D%C2%AB%C2%AB%22iQ2&input=%5B0%2C1%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C0%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%5D&debug=0)

Comment: At least in UTF-8, this weighs 19 bytes.

Comment: bytesizematters uses a completely made up way of counting bytes, which does not (and *cannot*) correspond to an actual encoding. It counts the square thingies as 2 bytes each (3 bytes in UTF-8) and `«` as 1 byte each (2 bytes in UTF-8). Both `wc` and [this](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#.HC%40%22%E0%AB%8E%E0%AB%8D%C2%AB%C2%AB%22iQ2) agree that it's 19 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 15 <s>16</s> <s>17</s> bytes

```
'Ali'B'C'Eli-+?
```

[**Try it online!**](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=J0FsaSdCJ0MnRWxpLSs_&input=MAox)

*One byte off thanks to @randomra, and one byte off thanks to @Dennis*

Explanation:

```
'A                  e# push "A"
  li                e# read first input as an integer
    'B              e# push "B" 
      'C            e# push "C"
        'E          e# push "E"
          li-       e# leave "E" or change to "D" according to second input
             +      e# concatenate "C" with "E" or "D"
              ?     e# select "B" or "C..." according to first input
```

---

Old version (16 bytes):

```
'Ali'B{'C'Eli-}?
```

Explanation:

```
'A                  e# push character "A"
               ?    e# if-then-else
  li                e# read first input as an integer. Condition for if
    'B              e# push character "B" if first input is true
      {       }     e# execute this if first input is false
       'C           e# push character "C"
         'E         e# push character "E"
           li       e# read second input as an integer
             -      e# subtract: transform "E" to "D" if second input is true
                    e# implicitly display stack contents
```

Comment: Our good friends Ali and Eli!

Answer (score 4):

## C, 76 bytes

I renamed `c1` to `c`, `c2` to `C` and `result` to `r`. C programmers go to extremes to avoid `goto`. If you ever have a problum with absurd syntax in C, it is most likely to be because you did not use `goto`.

```
char r[4]="A";if(c){r[1]=66;goto e;}r[1]=67;if(C){r[2]=68;goto e;}r[2]=69;e:
```

#### Ungolfed

```
char r[4] = "A";
if(c1){
    r[1] = 'B';
    goto end;
}
r[1] = 'C';
if(c2){
    r[2] = 'D';
    goto end;
}
r[2] = 'E';
end:
```

Comment: Can you start with `char r[4]="A";`? My C is rusty.

Comment: Isn't that a really ridiculous way of declaring a String literal?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Sort of.  String literals aren't writable.  It's an array which is then *initialized* by the string literal "A".  Since "A" only sets the first two bytes, the remainder is initialized per the rules for objects of static duration (so 0 in this case).  [C99 6.7.8/22]

Comment: You can save 22 bytes by changing the initialization list to `"AC"` and replacing everything from `r[1]=67` to `r[2]=69;` with `r[2]=c2?68:69;`

Answer (score 4):

### C, 41 bytes

I'm not sure if the question requires a program, a function or a code snippet.
Here's a function:

```
f(a,b){a=a?16961:4473665|b<<16;puts(&a);}
```

It gets the input in two parameters, which must be 0 or 1 (well, `b` must), and prints to stdout.

Sets `a` to one of `0x4241`, `0x454341` or `0x444341`. When printed as a string, on a little-endian ASCII system, gives the required output.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```r
pryr::f(c("ACD","ACE","AB")[1+a+a^b])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/oKiyyMoqTSNZQ8nR2UVJB0i6gkgnJc1oQ@1E7cS4pFjN/2kaIUGhrjoKIFKTC8Zzc/QJBnPBDIQslAuR/g8A)

In R, `TRUE` and `FALSE` are coerced to `1` and `0` respectively when you attempt to use them as numbers. We can convert these numbers to indices `1`, `2`, and `3` through the formula `1+a+a^b`.

```r
  a  |   b  | 1+a+a^b
TRUE | TRUE | 1+1+1^1 = 3
TRUE | FALSE| 1+1+1^0 = 3
FALSE| TRUE | 1+0+0^1 = 1
FALSE| FALSE| 1+0+0^0 = 2
```

These values are then used to index the list `ACD`, `ACE`, `AB` to yield the correct output.

Saved two bytes thanks to JayCe.

If instead you prefer a version with an `if` statement, there's the following for 41 bytes:

```r
pryr::f(`if`(a,"AB",`if`(b,"ACD","ACE")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/oKiyyMoqTSMhMy1BI1FHydFJSQfMTgKynV2UQKSrkqam5v80jZCgUFcdBRCpyQXjuTn6BIO5YAZCFsqFSP8HAA)

Comment: [you can save two bytes using `^`](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/oKiyyMoqTSNZQ8nR2UVJB0i6gkgnJc1oQ@1E7cS4pFjN/2kaIUGhrjoKIFKTC8Zzc/QJBnPBDIQslAuR/g8A)

Comment: @JayCe Thanks, I've updated the answer!

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>35</s> 30 bytes

```
If[#,"AB",If[#2,"ACD","ACE"]]&
```

Very simple. Anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 38 bytes

Use no-delimiter `0` or `1` instead of `false`/`true`

```
_=>"ACE ACD AB AB".split` `[+('0b'+_)]
```

Comment: You can use `split\` \``  instead of `split(" ")`

Comment: You can also use `+('0b'+prompt())` instead of `parseInt(prompt(),2)`

Answer (score 3):

### Retina, 22 bytes

```
1.+
AB
.+1
ACD
.+0
ACE
```

[Try it Online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MS4rCkFCCi4rMQpBQ0QKLiswCkFDRQ&input=MSAxCjEgMAowIDEKMCAw)

Comment: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MS4rCkFCCl4wIApBQwpUYGRgRUQ&input=MCAx.  Prefix the `^` with `m\``, to make it work for multi-line input, which is not necessary for the question, but makes testing easier.

Comment: I think you can save 3 bytes by removing the space between the two inputs.

Answer (score 3):

### [**Caché ObjectScript**](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS), 27 bytes

```
"A"_$s(x:"B",y:"CD",1:"CE")
```

Answer (score 3):

## [ArnoldC](http://mapmeld.github.io/ArnoldC/), 423 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE a
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE b
YOU SET US UP 0
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE a
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE b
TALK TO THE HAND "ABD"
BULLSHIT
TALK TO THE HAND "ABE"
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
BULLSHIT
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE b
TALK TO THE HAND "ACD"
BULLSHIT
TALK TO THE HAND "ACE"
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

Since ArnoldC doesn't seem to have formal input, just change the first 2 `YOU SET US UP` values to either 0 or 1 instead.

## Explanation

This is just a whole bunch of conditional statements which account for all the possible outputs. Why, you may ask? Well, ArnoldC doesn't really have string comprehension. It can't even concatenate strings! As a result, we have to resort to the more... inefficient... method.

Comment: Er, the output should be "AB" if a is true, not "ABD"/"ABE".  That should make your code shorter!

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 28 bytes

Same boilerplate as a lot of the answers. type is `BiFunction<Boolean,Boolean, String>`.

```
(c,d)->c?"AB":d?"ACD":"ACE"
```

Comment: I know it's been almost two years, but `(c,d)->` can be golfed by 1 byte to `c->d->` when you use a `java.util.function.Function<Boolean, java.util.function.Function<Boolean, String>>`.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 21 bytes

```
@c"ACE ACD AB AB"diz2
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40c%22ACE+ACD+AB+AB%22diz2&input=00&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=11%0A10%0A01%0A00&debug=0)

Input is taken as 0 or 1 instead of true/false while C1 comes first.

### Explanation

Just using the fact that there are only 4 possible results. Works by interpreting the input as binary, converting it to base 10 and using this to choose the right result from the lookup string.

```
@c"ACE ACD AB AB"diz2   # z= input

                  iz2   # Convert binary input to base 10
 c"ACE ACD AB AB"d      # Split string at spaces
@                       # Get the element at the index
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Y](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Y/), 20 bytes

In the event that the first input is one, only one input is taken. I assume that this behaviour is allowed. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Y/)

```
'B'AjhMr$'C'E@j-#rCp
```

Ungolfed:

```
'B'A jh M
   r$ 'C 'E@ j - # r
 C p
```

Explained:

```
'B'A
```

This pushes the characters `B` then `A` to the stack.

```
jh M
```

This takes one input, increments it, pops it and moves over that number of sections.

Case 1: `j1 = 0`. This is the more interesting one. `r$` reverses the stack and pops a value, `'C'E` pushes characters `C` and `E`. `@` converts `E` to its numeric counterpart, subtracts the second input from it, and reconverts it to a character. `r` un-reverses the stack. Then, the program sees the C-link and moves to the next link `p`, and prints the stack.

Case 2: the program moves to the last link `p`, which merely prints the entire stack.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 40 bytes

```
param($x,$y)(("ACE","ACD")[$y],"AB")[$x]
```

Nested arrays indexed by input. In PowerShell, `$true` / `1` and `$false` / `0` are practically equivalent (thanks to very loose typecasting), so that indexes nicely into a two-element array. This is really as close to a ternary as PowerShell gets, and I've used it plenty of times in golfing.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\do-while-false.ps1 1 1
AB

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\do-while-false.ps1 1 0
AB

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\do-while-false.ps1 0 1
ACD

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\do-while-false.ps1 0 0
ACE
```

Answer (score 2):

## K, 37 bytes

```
{?"ABCDE"@0,x,(1*x),(2*~x),(~x)*3+~y}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 26 bytes

Expects inputs as 1s or 0s through STDIN with a newline separating.

```
W([1m;]'DCA'W(Zr1+rZ
'BA'Z
```

<s>I actually discovered a serious problem with if statements during this challenge. D: This is posted with the broken version, but it works just fine. (I'll update this after I fix the problem)</s> Please note that I have updated Vitsy with a fix of if/ifnot. This change does not grant me any advantage, only clarification.

Explanation:

```
W([1m;]'DCA'W(Zr1+rZ
W                      Get one line from STDIN (evaluate it, if possible)
 ([1m;]                If not zero, go to the first index of lines of code (next line)
                       and then end execution.
       'DCA'           Push character literals "ACD" to the stack.
            W          Get another (the second) line from STDIN.
             (         If not zero, 
do the next instruction.
              Z        Output all of the stack.
               r1+r    Reverse the stack, add one (will error out on input 0, 1), reverse.
                   Z   Output everything in the stack.

'BA'Z
'BA'                   Push character literals "AB" to the stack.
    Z                  Output everything in the stack.
```

[Try it Online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=VyhbMW07XSdEQ0EnVyhacjErcloKJ0JBJ1o&input=MAow)

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 14 bytes

```
Ḥoị“ACD“AB“ACE
```

This expects the Booleans (**1** or **0**) as separate command-line arguments. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bikb-G7i-KAnEFDROKAnEFC4oCcQUNF&input=&args=MQ+MQ)

#### How it works

```
Ḥoị“ACD“AB“ACE  Main link. Left input: C1. Right input: C2.

Ḥ               Double C1. Yields 2 or 0.
 o              Logical OR with C2.
                2o1 and 2o0 yield 2. 0o1 and 0o0 yield 1 and 0, resp.
   “ACD“AB“ACE  Yield ['ACD', 'AB', 'ACE'].
  ị             Retrieve the string at the corresponding index.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax), 26 bytes

Interpreting `0` as false, `1` as true.

```
E`<
D`d"`C`~<
_T~T~`A`"b`B
```

Output:

```
julia> beeswax("codegolfdowhile.bswx",0,0.0,Int(20000))
i1
i1
AB
Program finished!

julia> beeswax("codegolfdowhile.bswx",0,0.0,Int(20000))
i1
i0
AB
Program finished!

julia> beeswax("codegolfdowhile.bswx",0,0.0,Int(20000))
i0
i1
ACD
Program finished!

julia> beeswax("codegolfdowhile.bswx",0,0.0,Int(20000))
i0
i0
ACE
Program finished!
```

Clone my beeswax interpreter from [my Github repository](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the quotes.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail: Okay, I’ll update my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>47</s> 45 bytes

Since there are only 3 different outcomes, we can pick one of three strings like this:

```c
char*f(c,d){return"AB\0 ACE\0ACD"+(!c<<d+2);}
```

Thanks to [Herman L](/users/70894) for 2 bytes

### Demo

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",
           f(1,1),
           f(1,0),
           f(0,1),
           f(0,0));
}
```

Comment: -2 bytes: `char*f(c,d){return"AB\0 ACE\0ACD"+(!c<<d+2);}`

Comment: link to TIO pls

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 23 bytes

```
say<>>0?AB:<>>0?ACD:ACE
```

Requires the `-E`|`-M5.010` flag and takes input as 1 and 0:

```
$ perl -E'say<>>0?AB:<>>0?ACD:ACE' <<< $'0\n0'
ACE
$ perl -E'say<>>0?AB:<>>0?ACD:ACE' <<< $'0\n1'
ACD
$ perl -E'say<>>0?AB:<>>0?ACD:ACE' <<< $'1\n0'
AB
```

Alternative solution that requires `-p` and is 22 + 1 = 23 bytes:

```
$_=/^1/?AB:/1/?ACD:ACE
```

```
perl -pe'$_=/^1/?AB:/1/?ACD:ACE' <<< '0 1'
```

Comment: `say-<>?AB:-<>?ACD:ACE` is two bytes shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>23</s> 20 bytes

Code:

```
Ii"AB"?q}"AC"?69I-ç?
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=SWkiQUIiP3F9IkFDIj82OUktw6c_&input=MQow)

Comment: This is probably an ancient version of 05AB1E, but it can be 14 bytes now: `i„ABë„AC69I-çJ` [Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/81HDPEenw6tBlLOZpafu4eVe//8bchkCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/i5ul5aGXM/8xHDfMcnQ6vBlHOZpaH1ukeXu71v1bnvyEXCBoAIZgEAA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice! This is indeed an ancient version of 05AB1E. The language was about three months old here (it did not even have implicit input).

Comment: Yeah, I was indeed already confused about the leading `I`. ;p

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 19 bytes

```
"A{U?'B:'C+(V?'D:'E
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=IkF7VT8nQjonQysoVj8nRDonRQ==&input=MCAx)

Fun fact: This would be 16 bytes if it weren't for a bug:

```
"A{U?"B:C{V?"D:E
```

Comment: Bugs are the worst :|

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Lemme see if I can dig out an older version that didn't have this bug. Then the 16 bytes would be legit.

Comment: What's the bug?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I believe nested strings like that don't transpile for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

## [SMBF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), 39 bytes

Each `_` represents a null literal `\x00` and is used for readability. I've successfully tested it for all test cases. 
<s>except the third, because I haven't found a way to test that input on my interpreter, since I'd need stdin to be `\x00\x01`. I know it works, though, because I used the exact same method for testing C2 as I did for testing C1.</s>

```
<.<,[<]<<.[>]>[<<<]<<<<,[<]<<.DE__BC__A
```

#### Explanation:

```
<.          print A
<,          read C1
[<]         if true, move left one
<<.         move left 2 and print (C if false, B if true)
[>]>        move to C1
[<<<]       if true, our output is done, so move all the way left, so further code is NOP
<<<<,       move left 4 and read C2
[<]         if true, move left one
<<.         move left 2 and print (E if false, D if true)
DE_ BC_ A   data on the tape
```

I think this will do the same for the same byte count, reusing B and C by adding 2 to each:

```
<.<,[<]<<.[>]>[<<]<<++<++>>,[<]<<.BC__A
```

Comment: Now I look at this and think "what was I doing, I could just increment A"... it might not be shorter, but I should've tried that first...

Comment: Try decrementing the inputs. Then you can nullterminate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 50 bytes

It is interesting what one can do with string templates.

```
{a,b->"A${if(a)"B" else "C${if(b)"D" else "E"}"}"}
```

[Try Here](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/upkbpd1ndqkld00vu767k3dt06/ce183rmq9c3vhkutruulvk506i)

Comment: Those quotations... _shivers_

Comment: Oh my god, the quotes actually match? ...

Answer (score 1):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse2002), 23 bytes

```
??"A"["B"|"C"["D"|"E"]]
```

Switches on two inputs, which each should be either `0` for `false` or anything else for `true`.

Ungolfed, as a function:

```
#Y,?,?;

$Y 1% a: 2% b:
  "A"
  a [
    "B"
  |
    "C"
    b [
      "D"
    |
      "E"
    ]
  ]
$
```

Brackets just test if the top of the stack is true, and `|` is `else`.

This is a translation of [@Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/c%e1%b4%8f%c9%b4%e1%b4%8f%ca%80-ob%ca%80%c9%aa%e1%b4%87%c9%b4)'s [ES6 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73494/46231).

Comment: Feature-request: These mentions actual should show up in my inbox >-<

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I know, right?

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 4.1, 19 bytes

I was expecting it to be harder, but well. It was really fun!

```
<?=A,$A?B:C.($B^t);
```

This expects 2 parameters/values, passed as strings over POST/GET/SESSION/COOKIE... The key `A` will have the first value, the key `B` will have the 2nd.
The result will be sent to STDOUT.

Answer (score 1):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 29 bytes

```
['A,^['B,]['C,$['D,]['E,]?]?]
```

<kbd>[Try it here!](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)</kbd>

Anonymous lambda. Usage:

```
1 0['A,^['B,]['C,$['D,]['E,]?]?]!
```

## Explanation

```
[                           ] {lambda}
 'A,                          {output A}
    ^                         {check if arg1 is truthy}
     [   ][               ]?  {conditional}
      'B,                     {if so, output B}
           'C,                {otherwise, output C...}
              $               {...and check if arg2 is truthy}
               [   ][   ]?    {conditional}
                'D,           {if so, output D}
                     'E,      {otherwise, output E}
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 18 chars / 23 bytes

```
`A⏜î?⍘B:`C⏜í?⍘D:⍘E
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=%5B0%2C0%5D&code=%60A%E2%8F%9C%C3%AE%3F%E2%8D%98B%3A%60C%E2%8F%9C%C3%AD%3F%E2%8D%98D%3A%E2%8D%98E)</kbd>

It's pretty much a fusion of conditional statements.

Note: `⏜` basically takes all code up to an optional `⏝`, interprets the code, and replaces that block in the code with the result. This is the first time I've used this in a submission, but it works quite well. Self-modifying code FTW!

Comment: This might be the most ASCII I've seen in an ESMin program

Answer (score 1):

## ><> (Fish), 30 bytes

```
"A"o$1+.
"<"DC"v"CE
o "B"|>oo;
```

This code uses the two variables (using the initial stack) to move the pointer to (C2, C1+1) [You can try it here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/Z2zkPffMw7TrEZZud)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 19 + 1 (-p switch) = 20 bytes

```
$ perl -pe '$_=l.$_^-su;s/B./B/'
00
ACE
01
ACD
10
AB
11
AB
```

Uses string XOR and a bareword with leading hyphen. Ungolfed:

```
$_ = ('l' . $_) ^ '-su';
s/B./B/;
```

Answer (score 1):

### QBIC, <s>39</s> 34 bytes

EDIT: Found out that QBasic (and by extension QBIC) doesn't need an `=1` to test if an input `is true`, so removed those.

```
_!_!~a_>?@AB._X]~b_>?@ACD._E?@ACE.
```

---

Original answer:

```
_!_!~a=1_>?@AB._X]~b=1_>?@ACD._X]?@ACE.
```

Takes two numerical inputs and tests these in straight-forward IF's. No fancy OR logic and array indexes here, unfortunately.

Comment: Interpreter link?

Comment: @tac http://gamegiver.blogspot.nl/2015/12/introducing-qbic-qbasics-belated-entry.html

Answer (score 1):

### C, 42 bytes (long version); 31 (short version)

The existing submissions seem inconsistent with regards to whether the variables must be named C1 and C2, and whether actually printing the results is required, so I've done a long and short version.

This approach takes advantage of the fact that most of the possibilities for each index differ by only one bit.

Long version:

```
char s[4]={65,67-C1,69*!C1&69-C2};puts(s);
```

Short version:

```
char s[4]={65,67-a,69*!a&69-b};
```

Answer (score 1):

## ForceLang,124 bytes

```
def f io.readnum()
set w io.write
set g goto
w "A"
if f
g L
w "C"
if f
g M
w "E"
g N
label L
w "B"
g N
label M
w "D"
label N
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 120 bytes

```
func w(b bool,d bool)(r string){
for i:=true;i;i=!i{
r+="A"
if b{r+="B"
break}
r+="C"
if d{r+="D"
break}
r+="E"}
return}
```

Go has only one loop structure, `for`, but you can simulate a do-while loop with `for i := true; i; i = expr`.

Edit: It also happens that Go's `switch` statement is flexible enough to replicate this.

```
switch {
case true:
    r += "A"
    if b {
        r += "B"
        break
    }
    r += "C"
    if d {
        r += "D"
        break
    }
    r += "E"
}
```

Comment: I miss my ternary operator :(

Answer (score 1):

## D, 35 bytes

```
(int a,int b)=>a?"AB":"AC"+"ED"[b];
```

Hey, look, D has lambdas.

Hey, look, D is JavaScript, but longer. :^(

Copied *verbatim* from Conor's [ES6 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73494/46231). c:

Comment: @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ here's your ping c:

Comment: [25](https://tio.run/##ZYxNCsIwEIX3PcUwqwSKB7CkUq2nEBcpSctAm0oy6kL06tH@ILRdvAfv8fGZSN2t9wyBze4X6rPk0ZOBTpMTEl5JYE@uAWNb22i2ghxDJZdbS6hV1CqvVK4PWBxxj8UJP3gu8VJdY5Y8PbFtnUD2d5vC0KBywBRqMQw5tdyQtW7DGh2/BTs@K@1Ebb0zuxTP8N/8jl8)

Answer (score 1):

## FALSE, 16 bytes

```
$"A"'C+,~['E+,]?
```

Input values are on the stack (first C2 then C1), false is 0 and true is -1 (this is normal in FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

## Hexagony, <s>28</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
A;?.));?~..>);@</E"+;@}/>
```

*-2 bytes by moving up the printing of **AB***

*-1 byte by incrementing to C instead*

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/19BQcFRwVrBXkFPgUtBQRMIQZw6IEcPCO2A2FrBQYHLRkFfwVVBSUEbwlWoBfLtwErA@vTgEMiBsf//N1QwAAA)

Expanded:

```
   A ; ? . 
  ) ) ; ? ~ 
 . . > . ; @ 
< / E " + ; @ 
 } / > . . . 
  . . . . . 
   . . . .
```

---

Uses the value of the second input to get the last char, removing the need for another costly branch:

```
"E" + (-1*C2)
```

*Credit to @JoKing*
Alternatively I could have also just subtracted the value which doesn't save any bytes though:

```
"E" - C2
```

Comment: Instead of negating, you could just change the `+` to a `-`. This doesn't actually save any bytes though

Comment: @JoKing i don't know how I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 25 bytes

```
'Aq~[{'C\['E'D]=}{;'B}]=~
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%27Aq%7E%5B%7B%27C%5C%5B%27E%27D%5D%3D%7D%7B%3B%27B%7D%5D%3D%7E&input=1%200)

Not the best way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

## Jolf, 16 bytes

```
+'A?j'B+'C."DE"J
```

Simple. [Try this one here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=KydBP2onQisnQy4iREUiSg)

Aother one, using that other Pyth answer's approach:

11 characters, 18 UTF-8 bytes. [You can try this one here.](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=flQuIuCrjuCrjcKrwqsizplq)

```
~T."૎્««"Ιj
          ^-- that's a capital Iota, converting input to binary
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brainbash](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Brainbash/), 43 bytes

```
----[>+<----]>++.>#{<+.>}-{<++.+>#-{<+>}<.}
```

Brainbash is BF with two tapes and more stuff. We're only using one this time. Let's take a look:

```
----[>+<----]>++.
```

This sets the first cell to `A` and outputs it.

```
>#
```

This move to the next cell and takes numeric input

```
{<+.>}
```

This is an if statement. If the numeric input is one, then we'll increment the previous cell and output it, outting `B`.

```
-
```

This transforms `1` to `0` (falsey) and `0` to `255`. It's effectively a boolean NOT as far as the next if statement is concerned.

```
{<++.
```

If the current bit, output a `C`.

```
+>#
```

Change it do a `D` and take some input

```
-
```

"Negate it"

```
{<+>}
```

If it was a zero, output an increment and return to input cell.

```
<.}
```

Move to destination cell and out it.

---

I could use the "heat death of the universe" to save two bytes, using `>+[+[<]>>+<+]>`, but that didn't complete in the online interpreter, which can be found in the link in the header.

Comment: Why does the "heat death of the universe" take until the heat death of the universe?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Because the Brainbash interpreter does not optimize the code.

Comment: How does the "heat death of the universe" code work, anyway?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy it uses one of the constant generators found on esolangs wiki page  "brainfuck constants"

Comment: The 15-long one doesn't work either? How sad.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy yeah. It's not like it's going to win anyhow :P

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```
@(x,y)[65,67-x,~x*(69-y),'']
```

This anonymous function will match all the test cases. The first input is `condition 1` and the second input is `condition 2`. The string will be returned.

The function also works with **Octave**. You can try it [online here](http://octave-online.net).

Simply create the anonymous function by running the command above, then call the function. Running this for example:

```
ans(0,1)
```

Will return:

```
ACD
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 54 bytes

Since the story started with a loop, I decided to stick to that. Not the shortest of solutions; but certainly one of the more obscure ones.

Function `f` takes two integer parameters as input (1 = true, 0 = false), and outputs `AB`, `ACD` or `ACE` to stdout.

```
f(a,b){for(int x=64;~putchar(++x)<<a&4;x+=x&2?!b:!a);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nustack](https://github.com/BookOwl/nustack/), 27 bytes

```
a"AB"*"AC"b{"E"}{"D"}if + |
```

Thanks to Morgan Thrapp and her Python answer for giving me the inspiration for this one.

Explanation:

```
a"AB"* /* Repeat "AB" 0 or 1 times, depending on if a is #t or #f. The result ("" or "AB") is put on the stack */
"AC" /* Put "AC" on the stack */
b{"E"}{"D"}if /* If b is true, push "E", else push "D" */
+ /* Concatenate the top two strings on the stack, push the result ("ACE" or "ACD") */
| /* Right now the stack looks like (x y). If x is truthy (not empty), keep x, else keep y */
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 43 Bytes

A different (more intuitive?) way to do it in JS. The name `parseInt` is not inductive of Code Golfing :P

```
"A"+["CE","CD","B","B"][parseInt(x+""+y,2)]
```

### Test:

```js
var cases = ["00","01","10","11"];
    
for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
   var x = cases[i][0];
   var y = cases[i][1];
   document.write("A"+["CE","CD","B","B"][parseInt(x+""+y,2)]+"<br>")
}
```

Comment: Try `+\`0b${x}${y}\`` instead of `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 31 bytes

Anonymous function; assign to a variable to test its output.

```
->x,y{?A+(x ??B:?C+(y ??D:?E))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 32 bytes

```
INPUT A,B?"A"+"CB"[A]+"ED"[B]*!A
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, <s>57</s> 52 bytes

```c++
[](auto c,auto&s){s="AC";c[0]?--s[1],s:s+='E'-c[1];}
```

First argument should be an indexable collection (vector, array, etc) of conditions, and second argument is the string to write to.

Assumes that the runtime character set has `B` and `C` contiguous, and `D` and `E` also contiguous (both are true for common codings such as ASCII and EBCDIC).

### Demo

```c++
auto const f = [](auto c,auto&s){s="AC";c[0]?--s[1],s:s+='E'-c[1];};

#include<array>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main()
{
    std::string s;

    for (bool c1: {true, false})
        for (bool c2: {true, false})
            f(std::array{c1, c2}, s),std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 54 bytes

I had orignally planned on using emit for this, but realized that direct string output was shorter (61 vs 54 bytes)

```forth
: f if ." AB" else if ." ACD" else ." ACE" then then ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKWSmKegpKTg6KSmk5hSnwrjOLlA@mOOqpFCSkZoHIaz/6xoqAFGaQnKRgkKMQrKhgq1CSVFpqo6CQrIRlM2lYKCggEdNWiLQcC6gKUB1KIrAEjpoBuFRA2b/BwA)

#### Explanation

If C1 is true, it prints `AB`, otherwise it prints `ACD` if C2 is true, and `ACE` if C2 is false

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                \ start a new word definition
   if              \ if c1 is true
      ." AB"       \ print "AB"
   else            \ if c1 is false
      if           \ if c2 is true
         ." ACD"   \ print "ACD"
      else         \ if c2 is false
         ." ACE"   \ print "ACE"
      then         \ end the inner if
   then            \ end the outer if
;                  \ end the word defintion
```